# In JS, I want to check for cookie and if not present, run an animation function and write cookie, and if so, skip animation.

Tags: javascript, animation, cookies

I've already made the animation functions, but I don't want it to animate every time the same person visits the site. So the plan is to check for the cookie and if it is there, skip the intro animation, but if it's not, I want to run the intro animation and create the cookie. I don't know a lot about cookies or Js, so I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Have you tried something already? A quick search for "javascript read cookie" shows good result explaining how to create and read cookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp. So please specify your problem, show us some code that is not doing what you need it to do

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm using for many projects.

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------
        global function for Set/Get Cookie
------------------------------------------------------*/

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

then set/get like:

SET:

`setCookie("c2u", c2u, 365);` NOTE: 365 is 365 day

GET:

`var cookieSelTimeZone = getCookie("selectedTimeZone");`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can create, read, and delete cookies with the document.cookie property. U can use any name/key you want like u use in PHP. 
You can then read from the cookie property to see if your key/value is set. 
[More info can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)